# React Native Push notification In Chat Application

Tags: firebase, react-native, aws-amplify, android-push-notification, react-native-push-notification

Currently, I'm building one chat application using react native amplify, it works fine when both users are online and are on the same screen ( stack screen to be specific ), I'm able to show push notifications to users for the new message using a react-native-push-notification package (local push notification).
I want to extend this functionality for app running in the background (similar to Whatsapp) and show push notifications if any new message comes for the user. I attempt to do so using FCM service, but found it's might not be best for messaging, and mostly used for campaigns.
Any better idea, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) and [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup) libraries

Comment: I have already implemented, react-native-push-notification but, as soon as I close the app or move away from the screen where I have a notification trigger, it stops working.